How do I retrieve the data of a created user, right before it is created?
Im working on a proyect using vite react and supabase. I have the option of logging in and signing up working, however, I cant figure out how to create a session when the user signs up.
I'm not using supabase auth, because I couldnt figure out how to implement it, so I'm using the insert function.
Signup.tsx
const createUser = async () => {    //This part prevents sending the form without an image for the avatar
        if(!formData.avatar){
            setError(true)
            setTimeout(() => {
                setError(false)
            },5000) 
        }
        else{
            try{
                const res = await supabase.from("users").insert([  //This part gets the inputs from the 
                    {                                              //form and inserts it on supabase
                        profilepic: `${formData.avatar}`,
                        name: `${formData.firstName}`,
                        last_name: `${formData.lastName}`,
                        email: `${formData.email}`,
                        password: `${formData.password}`,
                    }
                ])
                if(res.error){
                    throw res.error
                }
                if (res.status === 201) {            // This part (supposedly) creates a session with the 
                    setStatus(true);                 // the data from the form
                    setFormData(initialState);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('supabaseSession', JSON.stringify(formData))
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        setStatus(false);
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
            catch(error){
                console.error(error.message)
            }
            setTimeout(() => {
                navigate('/')                       // Lastly this redirects to the main page
            },2000)
        }
    }

I tried something that gpt suggested me, however is not very reliable because it only knows about older versions of supabase.
if (res.status === 201) {
                    const userId = res.data[0].id

                    setStatus(true);
                    setFormData(initialState);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('supabaseSession', JSON.stringify(formData))
                    sessionStorage.setItem('userId', JSON.stringify(userId))

                    setTimeout(() => {
                        setStatus(false);
                    }, 5000);
                }


You can get the newly inserted record by bdding .select() after your insert statement.
const { data, error } = await supabase.from( "users" ).insert({
    profilepic: `${ formData.avatar }`,
    name: `${ formData.firstName }`,
    last_name: `${ formData.lastName }`,
    email: `${ formData.email }`,
    password: `${ formData.password }`,
}).select()

Make sure to have both insert permission, and select permission on RLS policies.
You can click the button on the right of the docs to view different use cases. Read more in the Supabase documentation: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/insert?queryGroups=example&example=create-a-record-and-return-it.

